# how to detect a leading single-quote / CHAR(39) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

is there a way to detect a leading single-quote within a cell in Google Sheets?

cell A1 is set to:

```
'005
```

[image]

I was hoping to conditional format cells that contain leading `'` / `CHAR(39)` and paint the background blue.

Comment: It might help to know *why* you want to do this and what the range of applicable data might look like. For instance, most people use the leading single quote to retain leading zeros. If all of your instances that have the leading quote *also* fit the criteria that A.) they could be rendered as numbers and B.) they start with zero, then there is an obvious check for those entries that doesn't involved the single quote at all: `=ISNUMBER(A1*1)*(LEFT(A1)="0")`. If these conditions are not always true, is there any set of conditions that could be applied (and not applied to any other values)?

Comment: @ErikTyler dataset is a simple grid of 100×100 cells that contain various values, strings and formulae. the sheet itself is continuously attacked by rapid locale switching where the most reliable solution to keep formatting of those values, strings and formulae is to manually insert leading single-quote to multiple groups of cells before each / next locale switch. there is absolutely no way how to automate this whole process so manual labor is no problem. the issue arises with possible "track loss" of cells that did not get treated with single-quote so the switch wouldn't harm the locale forma

Comment: `manually insert leading single-quote to multiple groups of cells before each / next locale switch` Wouldn't it be easier to format them all as plaintext?

Comment: @TheMaster the preference of char(39) was chosen over plain text formatting due to faster (visual) ability to double-check the done cells from the pool of cells. the plaintext would do too as last resort but it's hidden under a layer of clicks & mouse movements and also I couldn't tell if it would be possible to target it and CF it from script.

Comment: Plain text formatting is a better alternative from apps script POV or even from a formula POV. `=TYPE()`, `=CELL()` all provide valuable information about the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change the background color of cells that have the cell values with `'` of top character to the blue color.
- Your goal includes using Google Apps Script.

In my experience, I thought that in this case, there might be no direct method for retrieving `'` of top character. Unfortunately, even when Sheets API is used, `'` cannot be retrieved. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Convert the sheet you want to use to XLSX format.
2. By parsing the XLSX data, detect the cells that have the cell values with `'` of top character.
3. Change the background color of the detected cells to blue color.

In Microsoft Docs, the detailed specification is published as Open XML. So, in this answer, by analyzing XLSX data, the cell coordinates of the cells with `'` of top character can be retrieved by using only the native methods of Google Apps Script. When this flow is reflected in Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet you want to use, and save the script. And, please set the sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // Convert Google Spreadsheet to XLSX format.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=${ss.getId()}&gid=${srcSheet.getSheetId()}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });

  // Retrieve the data from XLSX data.
  const blobs = Utilities.unzip(res.getBlob().setContentType(MimeType.ZIP));
  const { sheet, style } = blobs.reduce((o, b) => {
    const name = b.getName();
    if (name == "xl/styles.xml") {
      o.style = b.getDataAsString();
    } else if (name == "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml") {
      o.sheet = b.getDataAsString();
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Detect the cells including the single quote at the top character.
  const styler = XmlService.parse(style).getRootElement();
  const quotePrefix = styler.getChild("cellXfs", styler.getNamespace()).getChildren().map(e => e.getAttribute("quotePrefix") ? true : false);
  const sr = XmlService.parse(sheet).getRootElement();
  const ranges = sr.getChild("sheetData", sr.getNamespace()).getChildren().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.getChildren().forEach((c, j) => {
      const r = c.getAttribute("r").getValue();
      const v = Number(c.getAttribute("s").getValue());
      if (quotePrefix[v]) ar.push(r);
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Change the background color of detected cells.
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  srcSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("blue");
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, as a sample situation, the following situation is obtained. In this sample, in the input situation, the cells "A1:A3" has the value of `'500`. And, the cells "B1:B3" has the value of `500`. When this script is run, the background color of "A1:A3" is changed.

[image]

#### Note:

- About `resets color`, in this case, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      if (ranges.length == 0) return;
      srcSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("blue");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (ranges.length == 0) return;
      srcSheet.getDataRange().setBackground(null);
      srcSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("blue");
    ```
- Or, if you want to check only the cells with the blue background color, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      if (ranges.length == 0) return;
      srcSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground("blue");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (ranges.length == 0) return;
      const color = "#0000ff"; // This is blue.
      const r = srcSheet.getDataRange();
      r.setBackgrounds(r.getBackgrounds().map(r => r.map(c => c == color ? null : c)));
      srcSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setBackground(color);
    ```

#### References:

- [Understanding the Open XML file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats)
- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: I apologize in advance if I misunderstood your solution. is your answer suggesting to download the spreadsheet as XLSX file and opening that file with google sheets and applying the script to this XLSX spreadsheet? is this correct?

Comment: @player0 No. His script does all that automatically inside the script itself: downloading, extracting the xlsx, checking the xlsx and retrieving the quote prefix cell addresses from xlsx and then formatting the cells by the retrieved addresses.  The work done here is nothing short of legendary.

Comment: I tried it and I have some issues - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj17d.png  - did I run it incorrectly by not changing anything in the provided script? eg. should I somehow address the range within a script?

Comment: @player0 Thank you for replying. From your reply, I noticed that the method for retrieving the cell coordinate is required to be modified. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it again? In this sample script, all cells in a sheet are checked.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. In this case, the data is only retrieved from XLSX data. So, I thought that this script might be a bit simpler than recreating a Spreadsheet with modified XLSX data.

Comment: I can confirm the updated script works now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYXf7.png thank you for your work. I hope you won't mind if I may go with TheMaster's answer that detects changes between two script runs and resets color after the cell becomes null

Comment: @player0 Thank you for replying and testing it again. About `resets color`, I added the modification points in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thank you. yes, this modification - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNFnN.png - is exactly the behavior I imagined and hoped for because I have a lot of other colors all over

Comment: @player0 Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible with formulas or custom functions. But, you can do with `TextFinder` or the "Find and replace" functionality. Using regex's starting anchor `^`, we replace the cells to a formula and back to text. The differentiating factor is that cells with a single quote prefix cannot be converted to a formula using this method.

- `'005` => `'=005`(not a formula)
- `abc` => `=abc`(is a formula)
- `=1+5` => `==1+5`(still is a formula)

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * @description Detects single quotes in given range  and colors them 
 * @author TheMaster
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621052
 */
function detectSingleQuotePrefix(
  range = 'Sheet1!A1:E15',
  color = 'LightGoldenRodYellow'
) {
  const dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range),
    txtFinder = (
      /** @type {string} */ find,
      /** @type {string} */ replace,
      /** @type {boolean} */ matchFormula
    ) =>
      dataRange
        .createTextFinder(find)
        .matchFormulaText(matchFormula)
        .useRegularExpression(true)
        .replaceAllWith(replace),
    isEmpty = (
      /** @type {string} */ e,
      /** @type {number} */ i,
      /** @type {number} */ j
    ) => (e === '' && values[i][j] !== '' ? color : null);
  txtFinder('^.+', '=$0', false);
  const values = dataRange.getValues();
  const dividedColors = dataRange
    .getFormulas()
    .map((row, i) => row.map((col, j) => isEmpty(col, i, j)));
  txtFinder('^=', '', false);
  txtFinder('^=', '', true);
  dataRange.setBackgrounds(dividedColors);
  console.log(dividedColors);
}
```

Comment: this would do but it paints blue also empty/null cells for some reason (?) also, what did you mean by `cannot be converted` - does the script actually convert something to something else and then back to the original state or is this just a check with that textfinder ?

Comment: @player0 Are you using the latest version? It wouldn't touch empty cells. `^.+` ->It should at least have 1 character. Yes, it converts everything to a formula and checks if it is a formula. If it isn't, then there's a `'`. Then it converts everything back... all in a matter of milliseconds, so it's not visible.

Comment: I see. yes, I believe it's the latest version. testing it on a fresh sheet created on 26 Aug 2022 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC1mS.png

Comment: @player0 Should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

As per this **[Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905245#comment3)** it was confirmed that

> *"Update from spreadsheet team: A leading quote says that the remaining text should be treated as plain text. This behaviour is consistent with other spreadsheet products.
> "*

This would mean that it is an expected behaviour for the leading single quote/apostrophe to be hidden on any spreadsheet products *(not just in Google Sheets)*.

From my [research](https://superuser.com/a/1539521), the only workaround that I could find relevant is by using two single quotes/apostrophes *(if ever this would be applicable in your setup)* instead of using a single one before the cell value as seen below.

[image]

*Used `=FIND("'",B1)` for testing*

Comment: two single quotes are a nice idea but sadly it is not applicable in the current project. thx tho.