# Plus Symbol in front of a phone number converts it into a formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, replace, google-sheets-formula, find-replace

I have a list of over a thousand phone numbers in a google sheet. Many of these numbers have a plus symbol in the start. Google sheets is automatically converting this numbers to Formulas by replacing the `+` symbol with `=`
I read it [here](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/sheets/stop-the-plus-sign-from-generating-a-formula-in-sheets/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20there%27s%20an%20easy%20workaround,as%20just%20%2Bword%2Bword.) that adding an apostrophe `'` in front of the number will make sure that google sheet will read it as a plain text and not a formula. But its not possible for me to manually add an apostrophe in front of each number.
Also, the numbers have spaces in them so google sheet is throwing an error in a lot of cases.

e.g.
When I enter `+1 484 2918 914` , gsheet converts it into `=1 484 2918 914` and throws an `#ERROR` because of the space.
How can I convert this formula into a plain text?
Thanks a lot

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615734/how-to-detect-a-leading-single-quote-char39-in-google-sheets

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have your numbers lets say in one column and that column does not contains any valid formulae you can try with <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> like:

[image: llllllllllllllllllllllllllllll]