# Google Sheet API 4: How to return cell string value with leading single quotes as-is?

Tags: google-sheets-api, make.com, integromat-apps

Having a cell in Google Sheets with a value of `'0123` and fetching it via the API it returns `0123` and omits the leading single quote.

Tried to use any of the available [`ValueRenderOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) but always returns the cell value without single quote.

I would expect to get the single quote using the `UNFORMATTED_VALUE` or `FORMULA` value, but this is not the case.

Therefore: How to get the raw cell value, including leading single quotes?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the quote prefix of cell value cannot be directly retrieved using Sheets API and Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp of Google Apps Script). By this, there are no methods for checking whether the cell value has the quote prefix. But, fortunately, when Google Spreadsheet is converted to XLSX data, the quote prefix can be detected. You can see the sample script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73616511 . And, if you can use Google Apps Script, you can also use a Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#5-getquoteprefixcells)

Comment: If you want to use another language except for Google Apps Script, I think that when the same flow of the above sample script is achieved, your goal can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be an expected behavior given the fact that the feature just makes the system recognize the values after the apostrophe as text, so it is more like the cell formatting feature rather than an actual formula but without changing the format of the whole cell and just the values next to the apostrophe.

After making some testing in the API explorer from the Google Sheets API I found out that if you remove the apostrophe the API will definitely recognize the values as numbers when using either `UNFORMATTED_VALUE` or `FORMULA` in the `ValueRenderOption` parameter, so the API will return number values in the response, however if you do it using `'0123`, what you get in the response instead of numbers is text (see screenshots below).

#### Number value

[image]

#### Text value

[image]

With all this we can determine that this would be expected and that adding the apostrophe symbol is an exception to the `ValueRenderOption` parameter due to how the API works. I have also submitted feedback in the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) to see of Google can add this information to the documentation since there is no mention of this in that page.

#### References:

- [Using Apostrophe to Add Leading Zero](https://www.oksheets.com/add-leading-zeros/#:%7E:text=The%20apostrophe%20converts%20the%20number%20into%20text%20and%2C%20by%20doing%20so%2C%20keeps%20the%20leading%20zeros%20intact.)
- [Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting)