# Set apostrophe as a variable in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function which will find and replace all apostrophes in my google sheet.

This is the function:

```
function VymazApostrofu(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var f = "\'";
  var r = "";
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length;i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length;j++){
      if(data[j][i]==f)
      ss.getRange(j+1,i+1).setValue(r);
    }
  }  
}
```

The problem is, that I can not find the way, how to set the apostrophe as the variable f. Could you please help me?

I have tried double quotation, escape mark as , but nothing is working.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace the single quote `'` with `` (empty) using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `setValue` is used in a loop. In this case, I'm worried that the process cost becomes high.
- In the case of `data[j][i] == f`, when the cell value is only `'`, it becomes true. From `I have tried double quotation, escape mark as , but nothing is working.`, I think that this might be the reason for your current issue, and also, from your situation, in your actual situation, I guessed that the single quote might be included in a text in a cell.

When these points are reflected in a modified script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this sample script, all single quotes in the active sheet are removed.

```js
function VymazApostrofu() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var f = "'";
  var r = "";
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  range.createTextFinder(f).replaceAllWith(r);
  range.setValues(range.getValues());
}
```

- When this script is run, `'` of the cell value is replaced with the empty using TextFinder and `setValues`. (`'` is removed.) I thought that when TextFinder and `setValues` are used in your situation, the process cost can be reduced a little.
- As an important point, if the single quote is added to the 1st character of the cell value, this is used for using the cell value as a string. For example, `001` is put into a cell, it becomes `1`. But, `'001` is put into a cell, it becomes `001` of a text, while when you select the cell you can see `'001`. About this, this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73615734)

  - If you want to remove only the single quote of the top character of the cell value, please test the following pattern 2.

#### Modified script 2:

In this sample script, the single quotes of the top character of the cell value are removed.

```js
function VymazApostrofu2() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var f = "'";
  var r = "";
  range.createTextFinder(`^${f}{1,}`).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(r);
  range.setValues(range.getValues());
}
```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [replaceAllWith(replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceAllWith(String))

Comment: @Jan Haase About `It works perfectly. Thank you very much.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer