# Convert formulatext string to a formula in googleSheets +/- appscript

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to transpose a column containing strings of formulas and have them evaluate to a result in google sheets.

This breaks down into 2 questions. The first, is how to paste a string representing a formula in google sheets so that it evaluates to a result in google sheet without manually removing and adding an `=`

For example, if I

1. copy and paste values of `fomulatext()` in the sample table below from C2 `="I went with "& B4` this evaluateds to `="I went with "& B4`
2. if I copy and paste value of `="I went with "& B4` it evaluates to `="I went with "& B4`

However if I paste `"I went with "& B4` and then afterwards I manually add the "=" sign then google sheets will process the formula and evaluate to `I went with jake`

Similarly, I am experiencing the same issue as in the table below where I am trying to transpose the values of formulas and would like it to execute the equation rather than show the string of the equation so that the values for `transpose(C4:C6)=TRANSPOSE(D4:D6)`

**table**

| ROW | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | name | individual formulas | formulatext |
| 4 | jake | I went with jake | ="I went with "& B4 |
| 5 | sandy | I went with sandy | ="I went with "& B5 |
| 6 | sarah | I went with sarah | ="I went with "& B6 |
| 7 |  |  |  |
| 8 | I went with jake | I went with sandy | I went with sarah |
| 9 | ="I went with "& B4 | ="I went with "& B5 | ="I went with "& B6 |
| 10 |  |  |  |
| 11 | A6 | =transpose(C4:C6) |  |
| 12 | A7 | =TRANSPOSE(D4:D6) | end table |

Is there a way to do this in google sheets so that the transposed value will be treated as a formula rather than as a text string?

Tried appscript

```
  function transposeAndConvertFormulas() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'asdfjasdflasjdflk;asjfdlksajfa';
  var sourceRangeNotation = 'sheet!(range)';
  var destinationNotation = 'sheet!(cell)';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceRangeNotation.split('!')[0]);
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationNotation.split('!')[0]);

  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRangeNotation);
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  var transposedValues = transposeValues(sourceValues);
  var endCellNotation = calculateEndCell(destinationNotation, transposedValues[0].length);
  var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationNotation + ':' + endCellNotation);

  destinationRange.setValues(transposedValues);
}

function transposeValues(values) {
  var transposed = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (!transposed[j]) {
        transposed[j] = [];
      }
      transposed[j][i] = values[i][j];
    }
  }
  return transposed;
}

function calculateEndCell(startNotation, numberOfColumns) {
  var startColumn = startNotation.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
  var startRow = parseInt(startNotation.match(/\d+/), 10);
  var endColumn = columnToLetter(letterToColumn(startColumn) + numberOfColumns - 2);
  var endRow = startRow;
  return endColumn + endRow;
}

function letterToColumn(letter) {
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
}

function columnToLetter(column) {
  var letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    var temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: Jus curious on why this peculiar approach! Any advantage(s) we should know of?!

Comment: Context is trying to bulk update formulas in a spreadsheet, you might want to view the original formulas that are displayed across a particular Row in a column to make manual stepwise changes, Now you have applied changes across many formulas Now you wanna able to take those formulas and transposed Back to Source

Comment: What's the issue with Apps script?

Comment: not working, getting various errors.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615734/ and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303680/

Comment: I dont think so, I dont think there is a way to accomplish with a formula where the string of formulatext() gets automatically converted. I think it might require an appscript. If you are doing a single cell it is easy to manually remove the = sign and then add another. I will work on appscript.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations this may be solved by checking the formatting of the pasted values and then checking formatting, highlighting an entire row and switching from text to automatic or vice-versa might work if a cell displays =formula but is not being executed this can change behavior.

I am uncertain as to how google-sheets encodes the data under the hood. But it seems that sometimes changing these settings will not work and sometimes it will work.